# Dynamic loading in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, dynamic

I am working in a piece of code which loads a function (that receives 2 char pointers and an int and returns an int) from a dynamic library and it´s giving me trouble. I have no access to the library code. My code looks like this:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(char*, char*, int);
func_t funcptr;
void *lib = dlopen(library.so, RTLD_LAZY);
if(dlerror() != NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error at dlopen");
funcptr = (func_t) dlsym(lib, "function"); 
if(dlerror() != NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error at dlsym");
(*funcptr)(arg1, arg2, arg3);//arguments are correct, no problem there
dlclose(lib);
```

When I run it, it always throws both error messages and the function doesn´t execute. I have tried almost everything. Anybody can help?

EDIT: I have printed the strings returned by dlerror(): first it says "no such file or directory", and then "undefined symbol: function". I thought I might be searching in a wrong directory, so I checked it using getcwd and I am searching in the right directory.

Comment: What is the value of `library.so`? And you suppose to output the string returned by `dlerror()`, not just check whether it is `NULL`.

Comment: Print the string returned by dlerror(). It tells you what went wrong.

Comment: Also, read *carefully* [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).. Does your code compile? the `library.so` looks strange (perhaps you mean `"./library.so"` ....). Compile with `gcc -Wall -g` then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: In fact this is just a part of a larger program I have to complete for a university work. library.so is written by my teachers and they give me a Makefile to compile. I'll try with ./library.so anyway

Comment: It probably should be a literal string with a file path for some shared ELF executable. So the quotes `"` are absolutely essential! It is unclear if your code is compiling or not!

Comment: Now it works. Have trouble in another part of the code with pipes, but it doesn´t throws these errors anymore. Thanks a lot, Basile!!!!

Comment: I am also teaching (a little) at University. It amazes me how students are unable to *search* for then *read* documentation, while it is an essential skill for every software developer!

Comment: Also, it shouldn't be surprising if it throws *both* errors, the way that code is written. If the first step fails, you shouldn't expect any subsequent steps to succeed, and should probably restructure the code to not try `dlsym()` if `dlopen()` failed...

Answer (score 1):

Read *carefully* [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)..

<sup>Notice that `dlopen` has a strange but documented behavior when given a file name without `/`; so read carefully that man page several times!</sup>

The `library.so` looks very suspicious.... Do you really have a `library` variable with a field named `so`? Maybe you want a literal string `"library.so"` instead. Then try

```
typedef int (func_sig_t)(char*, char*, int);
func_sig_t* funcptr;
void *lib = dlopen("./library.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!lib) 
  { fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror()); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
funcptr = (func_sig_t*) dlsym(lib, "function");
if (!funcptr) 
  { fprintf(stderr, "dlsym failed: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
int res = funcptr(arg1, arg2, arg3);
dlclose (lib);
funcptr = NULL;
```

Compile with `gcc -Wall -g`. And also **use the `gdb` debugger**!